# rails find_by_sql LIKE escaping %

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, find-by-sql

I am trying to execute a find_by_sql statement which involves a SELECT statement with a LIKE operator. For sake of brevity, let's assume the statement is "SQL * FROM posts where lower(name) LIKE '%hello%'"

Seems like rails throws an exception about "% being a malformed format string". I have tried to escape the sql statement using "SQL * FROM posts where lower(name) LIKE '\%hello\%'"

Still the same error message shows up. Any ideas ?

Comment: +1 just because it never occurred to me to use lower(fieldname) when comparing strings...